# Is all DOM nodes inherit from DOM Node interface?

Tags: dom

I'm confusing about this point since almost all DOM nodes are some sub-interface of the Node interface, but I can't find the precise definition that can prove this. Is there anybody know more about this? thanks.

Comment: Well... If they are DOM Nodes, then yes, they should inherit from the Node interface... Can you clarify where your confusion comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, all nodes inherit from the [**DOM Node interface**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node):

> The following interfaces all inherit from Node’s methods and properties: `Document`, `Element`, `CharacterData` (which `Text`, `Comment`, and `CDATASection` inherit), `ProcessingInstruction`, `DocumentFragment`, `DocumentType`, `Notation`, `Entity`, `EntityReference`

And also, **[according to W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247)**:

> The Node interface is the **primary** datatype for the entire Document Object Model. It represents a single node in the document tree. While all objects implementing the Node interface expose methods for dealing with children, not all objects implementing the Node interface may have children. For example, Text nodes may not have children, and adding children to such nodes results in a `DOMException` being raised.